# c# .net change label text

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, label

Hello for I trying to use this code but for some reason it doesn't work. Really need help with this. The problem is that the label doesn't change name from "label" when I enter the site.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="label"></asp:Label>


<% 
    Label1.Text = "test";
    if (Request.QueryString["ID"] != null)
    {

        string test = Request.QueryString["ID"];
        Label1.Text = "Du har nu lånat filmen:" + test;
    }

     %>
```

Comment: You should be getting an error for an unquoted string, it needs to be `Text='label'`, is this just a copy error in the question post?

Comment: Did you try putting a break point in your if statement and run the debugger to check that your code setting the Text property is actually reached?  Also there is a typo in your <asp:Label> tag for the Text attribute where you are missing some quotes so if you copied your code directly from your apsx page then I am surprised that it actually compiles and runs :-)

Comment: Are you sure QueryString["ID"] in not null?

Answer (score 9):

you should convert test type >>>> test.tostring();

change the last line to this :

```
Label1.Text = "Du har nu lånat filmen:" + test.tostring();
```

Answer (score 4):

Old question, but I had this issue as well, so after assigning the Text property, calling `Refresh()` will update the text.

```
Label1.Text = "Du har nu lånat filmen:" + test;
Refresh();
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried running the code in the Page_Load() method?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

         Label1.Text = "test";
        if (Request.QueryString["ID"] != null)
        {

            string test = Request.QueryString["ID"];
            Label1.Text = "Du har nu lånat filmen:" + test;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you may be experiencing the problem because in order to be able to set the labels "text" property you actually have to use the "content" property.

so instead of:

```
  Label output = null;
        output = Label1;
        output.Text = "hello";
```

try:

```
Label output = null;
            output = Label1;
            output.Content = "hello";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  Label label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label
//label1.Text = "test";
    if (Request.QueryString["ID"] != null)
    {

        string test = Request.QueryString["ID"];
        label1.Text = "Du har nu lånat filmen:" + test;
    }

   else
    {

        string test = Request.QueryString["ID"];
        label1.Text = "test";
    }
```

This should make it

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem I could see only a part of my text and this is the solution for that:

Be sure to set the AutoSize property to true.

`output.AutoSize = true;`